# Shrink DIV with flex-wrap

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I have problem with flex-wrap. When I set it and set width of child to 100% (to take entire "line"), it dont shrink.

Look at my code:
https://codepen.io/dinoq-the-reactor/pen/OJRJoNm

HTML:

```
<div id="main-container">  
  <div id="sub-container">
    <div class="flex-container">
    <div id="i1" class="flex-item">Icon</div>
    <div id="i2" class="flex-item">some text, flex it!</div>
    <div id="i3" class="flex-item">Icon</div>
    <div id="i4"  class="flex-item">Text on new line</div>
    </div>
  <div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
#main-container{
  width: auto;
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 9900;
}

#sub-container{
  width:100%;
}

.flex-container {
  background-color:blue;
  display: flex;
   flex-wrap: wrap;
  
}

.flex-item {
  border: solid 1px green;
  border-collapse: collapse;
  background: grey;
  color: white;
  font-size: 3em;
}

#i2{
  flex: 1;
}
#i4{
  flex: 0 0 100%;
}
```

What I want is to achieve something like this:

[image: What I want]

Instead I got this:
[image]

Note: I really need use "flex-wrap" and html structure which I have... It is part of bigger project, and I can edit only CSS...

Note2: My container is so expanded because width of it is width of all child elements, so it counts width of my 4. child (which is on new line). This is some source of problem, but how it solve?

Thanks!

Comment: grid is maybe a better option : https://jsfiddle.net/Lh5asqjb/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Below is the solution for your problem.

```css
#main-container {
  width: auto;
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 9900;
}

#sub-container {
  width: 100%;
}

.flex-container {
  background-color: gray;
  font-size: 0;
}

.flex-item {
  border: solid 1px green;
  border-collapse: collapse;
  color: white;
  font-size: 3em;
  display: inline-block;
  font-size: 3rem;

}

.flex-item:last-child {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="fr">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" name="viewport" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="./style.css" />
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="main-container">  
  <div id="sub-container">
    <div class="flex-container">
    <div id="i1" class="flex-item">Icon</div>
    <div id="i2" class="flex-item">some text, flex it!</div>
    <div id="i3" class="flex-item">Icon</div>
    <div id="i4"  class="flex-item">People of this world are travellers</div>
    </div>
  <div>
</div>
  </body>
</html>
```